# What is this succulent with 4 stacks of leaves?

Tags: identification, succulents

The one at the very bottom is [*Sedum makinoi*](http://worldofsucculents.com/sedum-makinoi/), right? What about the tall one?

[image: Sedum?]

Comment: I don't think they're separate plants, if you're referring to the small green growths  at the base as being distinct from the columnar stack behind, nor do I think its any kind of Sedum, its more like one of the stacked Crassulas, but I'm not expert enough to identify this particular one.

Comment: The two look like the same 'succulent'...the same plant.  The colored one is coleus.  Where do you live and how did these plants get to be planted together?

Comment: @stormy - The one who took the picture said this was in Missouri, US.

Comment: J. Musser knows succulents as well as tons of other great stuff about plants and landscapes.  I just have one observation to make and that is the combination of this succulent and the coleus.  The two have such divergent needs...one needs constant moisture the other hardly none.  Just a FYI.  Pretty succulent this Portulaca...so architectural!  Coleus...gorgeous back ground.  The Coleus is short lived unless pruned correctly to stay new and fresh confined in a pot.  So one season what a fun combination...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be [*Portulaca molokiniensis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca_molokiniensis), or 'Ihi'. It's an endangered species. Not Sedum. The short offsets are part of the same root system as the long stem.

Very nice, I'd definitely try to keep it alive. From the way the end of the long stem seems to be branching, you'll have flowers soon!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks :-) The owner of the plant had no idea what it was.

Comment: Wow, @J. Musser!  Very nice.